# MySQL select SUM of results with a LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table full of items and prices for said items.  I would like to grab the SUM of the 3 highest priced items.

I thought perhaps `SELECT SUM(items.price) FROM items ORDER BY items.price LIMIT 3` but that does not seem to do the trick.  Is this possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
select sum(price) from (select items.price from items order by items.price desc limit 3) as subt;
```

Answer (score 17):

`LIMIT` affects the number of rows returned by the query and SUM only returns one. Based on [this thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,105508,105543#msg-105543) you might want to try:

```
SELECT sum(price) 
FROM (SELECT price
      FROM items
      ORDER BY price DESC
      LIMIT 3
) AS subquery;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a sub-select:

```
select sum(prices) from (SELECT SUM(items.price) FROM items ORDER BY items.price LIMIT 3) as prices
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery or something like that. Just an idea, as I have not tested the actual query.

```
SELECT SUM(items.price) from (select price FROM items ORDER BY items.price LIMIT 3)
```

Comment: Right answer except that it seems when I write `SUM(items.price)` the query fails, but leaving out the table ie. `SUM(price)` the query works

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested this and I just wrote it on my memory. You could try something like:

```
SELECT * AS total FROM items ORDER BY price DESC
SELECT SUM(price) FROM total LIMIT 3;
```

Edit: I was slow

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Please remove this answer otherwise you might get lots of downvotes.